# How to get rid of weekend dates with my javascript function?

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, ruby, json, ruby-on-rails-4

I have a javascript function that looks at my leave_start and leave_end datepickers then it figures out all the dates in between leave_start and leave_end. Which works great, but question is lets say someone picked 4/10/15 which is a Friday for leave_start then for leave_end picked 4/13/15 which is a Monday this would give me all of the dates like this 4/10/15, 4/11/15, 4/12/15, 4/13/15. How can I get it to just show me the dates that aren't on the weekend which would just be 4/10/15, 4/13/15? any help would be greatly appreciated!

## side note Using ruby on rails 4+

This is my app.js

```
 $(document).ready(function() {


     $('.customSub').click(function() {

         var start = $('#leave_start').datepicker("getDate"),
             end = $('#leave_end').datepicker("getDate"),
             currentDate = new Date(start),
             between = []
         ;

         while (currentDate <= end) {
             between.push(new Date(currentDate));
             currentDate.setDate(currentDate.getDate() + 1);
         }
         var date_start = new Date();


         var formated_dates = between.reduce(function(dates, the_date){
             dates.push(date('m-d-Y' + ' ' , the_date));
             return dates;
         }, []);
         // Figures out dates in between leave_end and leave_start and puts the value of it in gdates text_field
         $('#gdates').val(formated_dates.join("\n"));

    });
  });
```

## Additional info

This is my view

```
.row-fluid
   =simple_form_for @entry, :url => url_for(:controller => 'entry', :action => 'create'), :method => :post do |f|



     %table.table.table-bordered.table-striped{:style => 'table-layout:fixed; width:100% !important;'}
       %th.lt Leave Start:
       %td.lt= f.text_field :leave_start,  :label => false, :id => 'leave_start', :input_html => {:value => ''}
       %td.lt= f.error :leave_start, :class => 'er'

     %table.table.table-bordered.table-striped{:style => 'table-layout:fixed; width:100% !important;'}
       %th.lt Leave End:
       %td.lt= f.text_field :leave_end,  :label => false, :id => 'leave_end', :input_html => {:value => ''}
       %td.lt= f.error :leave_end, :class => 'er'


     %td.lt= f.text_field :range_days, :label => false, :id => 'range_days', :input_html => {:value => ''}
     %td.lt= f.text_field :full_range, :label => false, :id => 'gdates', :input_html => {:value => ''}


     %table.table.table-bordered.table-striped{:style => 'table-layout:fixed; width:100% !important;'}
     = f.button :submit, "Submit", :class => 'customSub', :style => 'margin-left:50px;'
```

Comment: Can you use javascripts `.getDay()` function against the dates just before returning them (0 to 6 based); Sunday is 0, Monday is 1, and so on?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change this block of code to suit...

```
while (currentDate <= end) {
    if (currentDate.getDay() % 6 > 0) {
        between.push(new Date(currentDate));
    }
    currentDate.setDate(currentDate.getDate() + 1);
}
```

It checks the day of the week and ignores days that are 0 or 6 (Sunday is 0, Saturday is 6).